# How to create Right side Navbar with md-sidenav in Angular Material - Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-material2

I am trying to create "right navbar" with angular material 2 `md-sidenav`. No matter what I do, it is always coming on the left. How can I change this to right sidenav instead?

```html
  <md-sidenav #sidenavright mode="side" class="app-sidenav" opened="true">
    <app-question-rightnav></app-question-rightnav>
  </md-sidenav>
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Okay, it's easier than I thought, silly me!!

To align md-sidenav to right side, just add `align="end"` to `md-sidenav` element.

```
  <md-sidenav align="end" #sidenavright mode="side" class="app-sidenav" opened="true">
    <app-question-rightnav></app-question-rightnav>
  </md-sidenav>
```

## Update

It's changed to `position="end"` in the later versions

**Example**

```
<mat-sidenav #sidenavright position="end">
       Right sideNav
</mat-sidenav>
```

Comment: Update:  This should be `position="end"` now

Answer (score 10):

```
<mat-sidenav-container>

    <mat-sidenav #right position="start">
       Start Sidenav.
    </mat-sidenav>

    <mat-sidenav #left position="end">
       End Sidenav.
    </mat-sidenav>

<div>
    <button mat-button (click)="right.open()">right</button>
    <button mat-button (click)="left.open()">left</button>
</div>

</mat-sidenav-container>
```